Banach-Steinhaus Thm: why set X_n is closed? (Continuity of supremum?)
In the context of Banach-Steinhaus theorem, what is a detailed proof of a statement that $X_n:=\{x\in X| \sup_{T\in F}\|T(x)\|_{Y} \leq n \}$ is a closed set? (X is a Banach space, Y normed vector space, T is from a subset of B(X,Y), a set of continuous linear functions from X to Y)
My attempt:

$T(.)$ is continuous
$\|.\|_{B(X,Y)}$ is continuous
is $\sup_{T\in F}(.)$ somehow continuous (?) (How to prove it? I really doubt such approach); sup is a lowest upper boundary of a set, how it treats continuity?
[0,n] is a closed set
composition of continuous functions is continuous
preimage under continuous function of a closed set is closed.


Write $X_n$ as an intersection of closed sets.

You can use that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $T_\varepsilon \in F$ such that $\sup_{T \in F} \lVert T(x) \rVert_{B(X, Y)} < \lVert T_\varepsilon(x) \rVert_{B(X, Y)}+ \varepsilon$ which will help you to prove continuity.

I think you're making this more complicated than necessary.  There are no deep continuity properties required here.  Instead, simply note that for any set $A$ of real numbers and any number $y$, we have $\sup A \le t$ if and only if we have $s \le t$ for all $s \in A$.

@NateEldredge F is a subset of B(X,Y). Fixed the typo, now it is T instead of T(x).

But now you have $X_n$ defined as the set of all $x$ such that (predicate not involving $x$).  Are you sure you don't mean $|T(x)|Y$ instead of $|T|{B(X,Y)}$?  That's what you would typically have in the Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

@NateElredge totally true, sorry, yes

Thanks everybody, there is no need for further comments(intersection and equivalence comments helped). If anybody else need it, write me, i will write an answer.
